# SMPP session sequence id max value

Tags: session, networking, tcp, smpp

I have a SMPP Adaptor and it will be connecting to messaging gateway 24/7 and the session sequence number increases sequentially.

Does this sequence id has a max value? What will happen after it reaches its max value? Will it automatically reset to 0?

OR Do I need to reset the connection to control this sequence id.

Answer (score 2):

I've always put myself the same question.

In SMPP, the sequence number may range from `0x00000001` to `0x7FFFFFFF` (1 to 32767) - it is equivalent to a positive signed 16 bits integer.

The sequence number should be increased monotonically for each submitted SMPP request and in case it reaches its maximum value, it should be reset to `0x00000001`.

For more details you can take a look to [SMPP v3.4 Specification](http://docs.nimta.com/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf) - chapter 5.1.4 and [SMPP v5.0 Specification](http://docs.nimta.com/smppv50.pdf) - chapter 4.7.24.

Answer (score 1):

The specification states that sequence number may range for both *SMPPP 3.4* and *SMPP 3.5* between **1** and **2147483647**. Once the sequence_number reaches max, it should start again from min value.

Specification states that sequence number is defined with 4 octets, so in theory(and in practice) an operator could use numbers greater than 2147483647 *(2^31 -1)*, pushing it outside specified range.

From the *SMMPP 3.4* and *SMPP 5.0* specifications:

> The sequence_number may range from:
>   0x00000001 to 0x7FFFFFFF.
>
> **sequence_number**
>
> - size octects: 4
> - type: Integer
>
> There is no specific requirement on how the sequence_number should be set. However, it is recommended
>   that the sequence number be a monotonically increasing number.